# Display Job Post of individual user id in WP JOB manager

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I m trying to display Job listing of individual user based on User ID in his respective account as **"My Listing"**.
I checked there forum still didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom query and to include the current user id.  Something like this:

```
      $user = wp_get_current_user();

      $args = array(
        'author'                 => $user->ID,
        'post_type' => 'job_listing',
      );

      $query = new WP_Query( $args );
      $query->the_post();

      if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

           //Loop Content Here
        }
      }
```